# AlertDialoug focusing on EditText when dismissed.. causing Keyboard to appear.. what to do?

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I am using an AlertDialog to pop up and ask the user for some information, when the user clicks on a button.

The dialog is working fine, and I get the user info it dismisses itself.

However when the app returns focus to my primary view.. it is setting the focus to an EditText widget which causes the keyboard to appear for that View.

I don't want the Keyboard to appear unless the user explicitely puts focus on that field, so how do I change/override the default behavior, so that it doesn't autofocus on this field after the AlertDialog is dismissed.

It doesn't behave this way when the view initially inflates, the field is focused (highlighted), but the keyboard is not visible, only after the user taps on the field does the keyboard come up when the app launches.  This behavior after dialog dismiss is completely different.. any ideas?

(No the EditText is not anywhere near the buttons of the alert dialog, so its not as though a second tap or something is happening accidentally or the click is being passed up the stack.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was as stated in comments above, I was not dismissing the keyboard from the ALERTDIALOG, I was working on the false assumption that when the dialog was dismissed that the keyboard would be as well.  This assumption was wrong.

The keyboard for the alert dialog was not dismissed, the view returned to the parent view and because the edit text in the parent view got focus the keyboard updated itself to appear properly for this view.

The attempts to dismiss keyboard in the dialog dismiss listener did not remove the keyboard because they were trying to dismiss the keyboard for fields in the parent window and at the time of their execution it was still tied to the field in the alertview.

Add the dismisskeyboard calls to the onclick events that dismissed the dialout for the edittext fields in the alertDialog resolve the problem.

Comment: See Below for more detailed discussion.  THanks to Femi for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this after the dialog is dismissed:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: I guess the problem is, I don't know what event to trap to capture when the alertdialog has been dismissed.  I have it calling the hidekeyboard calls in the dialog class itself on all buttons, but this doesn't solve the issue because it is when it returns to the parent screen after the dialog is closed that the edittext gets focus.  So I guess the real question is, what do I need to do, to catch that the alert has closed and execute my hideKeyboard method?

Comment: You already have an OnDismissListener set (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html)? Ah, just submitted and saw your update. Good.

Comment: Femi.  I Did, but no dice, the OnDismiss is called PRIOR to the underlying view being redisplayed and the EDITTEXT getting focused..So onDismissListener gained me nothing unfortunately.  It seems like Android is doing something with the view after the alertDialog is dismissed, redrawing, or refocusing or something that is causing this EditText to become focused and making its Keyboard Appear.. I have no idea what this is, but something is going on

Comment: Odd: maybe try attaching a focus listener to the edit text in the OnDismissListener and then hiding the keyboard and removing the focus listener? Kind of a bad hack, but might get you off the ground. I expect you'll figure out what exactly is causing the craziness in time, but that might take a while.

Comment: Femi, I figured it out.. I was not dismissing the keyboard for the inputs in the dialog... so it was carrying it back to the main window.  I added hiding the dialog editexts to the onDismiss, and this did nothing... I guess the Dialog was already GONE so it ignored the dismiss.. however when I added my the dismiss keyboards to the dialog items in the onclick methods this solved the problem.  It is still VERY strange that it held the keyboard that was tied to a view in a dialog that was gone and kept it in the main view to me,

Comment: I was working under the assumption that once the VIEW/DIALOG that the keyboard was tied to for input was dismissed that Android would have been smart enough to dismiss the keyboard as well.. It apparently was not.  So all my calls to dismiss keyboards on my mainview edittexts had no effect...  Which also was odd, since the keyboard clearly changed when the dialog was dismissed to the proper input keyboard type for the edittext in my main view.. So not only did it retain the keyboard, it linked it to the focused item in the main window, and ignored calls on that widget to dismiss it odd indeed.

Comment: Interesting: you are right that I would have thought the keyboard would autodismiss when the dialog closes, but I'm guessing the keyboard visibility is attached to the Window object state and strictly speaking the Dialog is part of the Activity's Window so it would persist. It would go away if you launched another Activity (which would be a different Window), but not if you just launched/closed a Dialog.

Comment: Femi, you are very right. I was facing a very odd situation in which soft keyboard appears when clicking on editText inside a alert dialog but once I close the alert dialog, keyboard does not disappear. To close the keyboard, I obtained the mainView of activity and used  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mainview.getWindowToken(), 0); Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can ask the `InputMethodManager` to resign the keyboard when you dismiss the dialog:

```
EditText mValue; //The input view in your Dialog

//Close the keyboard
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mValue.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Hope that Helps!

Comment: Wireless,  I tried that.. I have a method that hides all keyboards.. bascailly calling the hideSoftInputFromWindow as in your example code, but with mValue being every editText widget in my app and I do call it on dismissal of the AlertDialog... but the Focus of the EditText happens AFTER the alert dialog is dismissed, so it just brings up the Keyboard for that EditText Field.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear...It's likely not that EditText being focused that causes the issue.  It takes more than just focus to bring up an InputMethod.  It's the EditText item(s) IN your dialog that are attached to the IME (those are what mValue represents).  Call this code when the buttons are clicked to dismiss the dialog before it is actually dismissed.